# Componente combo selecionado

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, combobox

Estou com um problema ao carregar a tela com um item do combo selecionado.
Já tentei com jQuery, angular e não funcionou. Já pesquisei em outras respostas por aqui e não funcionou nenhuma das alternativas.
Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser ?

```
    <div class=" form-group col-md-3">
       <label class="lb">A Rendimento</label> 
         <select  ng-change="selecionaArendimento(nota.flagARendimento)" id="flagRendimento"  ng-model="nota.flagARendimento" class="form-control">
              <option  ng-selected="selected" value="0">Não</option>
              <option value="1" >Sim</option>                 
         </select>
      </div>
```

Comment: Não precisa disparar um evento change no combo?

Comment: @dvd não entendi o teu questionamento...

Comment: Me parece que uma função é chamada quando a opção do combo é alterada (change)... ao carregar a página, é preciso disparar o evento change senão nada acontece sem que o usuário altere uma opção do combo.

Comment: Você quer que o combo fica selecionado no item que está na model `nota.flagARendimento`, é isso?

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e poste tbm o controller com o javascript para ficar mais claro!

Comment: @RicardoPontual sim!

Comment: entendi, coloquei uma resposta com o exemplo de código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-selected` deve ser uma expressão lógica, pode ser feito assim:

```
<select  ng-change="selecionaArendimento(nota.flagARendimento)"  ng-model="nota.flagARendimento" class="form-control">
  <option ng-selected="nota.flagARendimento == '0'" value="0">Não</option>
  <option ng-selected="nota.flagARendimento == '1'" value="1">Sim</option>                 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tens de comparar no `ng-selected` o valor da `option` com o que tens em `nota.flagARendimento`

```
<option ng-selected="nota.flagARendimento == 0" value="0">Não</option>
<option ng-selected="nota.flagARendimento == 1" value="1">Sim</option>
```

E creio que podes remover o `ng-change` do `select`, ao especificares `ng-model` ele já deve actualizar o que definires em `ng-model` com o novo valor seleccionado, neste caso `nota.flagARendimento`.

O que deves fazer é chamar a função `selecionaArendimento` quando o `nota.flagARendimento` muda.